# What's Python's next() in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am currently learning Ruby and am lost a bit.

This Python snippet:

```
n = iter([1,2,3,4,5])
for x in n:
  print(x)
  y = next(n)
  print(y)
```

gives:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

And I'm trying to do the same in Ruby, which is not working:

```
n = [1,2,3,4,5].each

for x in n do
  puts x
  y = n.next()
  puts y
end
```

How do I need to write the Python example in Ruby?

Comment: Here's a link to the docs: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html#method-i-each.  It has an example that seems close to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Considering that knowledge of both Python and Ruby are needed to answer your question, you should add a "python" tag. That will also greatly expand the number of members that see your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea except Ruby keeps track of the position of the enumerator internally. Try this:

```
enum = [1,2,3,4,5].each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:each>    
loop do
  puts enum.next
  puts enum.next
end
1
2
3
4
5
```

[Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) raises a *StopInteration* exception when invoked after all elements of the enumerator `enum` have been generated. [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles the exception by breaking out of the loop.

Note that [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-each), without the optional block, has the same effect as [Object#to_enum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Object.html#method-i-to_enum). Also, though authors of Ruby books feel an obligation to cover `for` loops (seemingly, on page one), they are *never* used in practice.

Comment: _"except Ruby keeps track of the position of the enumerator internally"_ – what do you mean by that?

Comment: Calling n.next() inside the for loop doesn't change the position of the for loop's Enumerator.

Answer (score 1):

In Python the [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-iterator) `n` obtained applying the function [iter()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#iter) **can be consumed once**.

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
n = iter(array)

for x in n:
  print(x)

# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
```

If you then call `next(n)` you get no output but error: [StopIteration](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration). If you try to iterate n again you get no output (no error, the for loop hanldes the exception).

But you can iterate over the array:

```
for x in array:
  print(x)
```

If you **check the output a code like yours**, you get:

```
n = iter([1,2,3,4,5])
for x in n:
  print('odd_', x)
  y = next(n)
  print('even', y)

# odd_ 1
# even 2
# odd_ 3
# even 4
# odd_ 5

# StopIteration
```

---

As pointed by @toniedzwiedz [Object#to_enum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Object.html#method-i-to_enum) is the equivalent for the Python `iter()`, so you can call [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) on it.

In **Ruby you can consume more than once** the enumerator:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = array.to_enum
# n = array.each # each returns an Enumerable

for x in n do
    puts x
end

for x in n do
    puts x
end
```

Since you can consume more than once the enumerator **you get "double" output**:

```
for x in n do
    p x
    p n.next
end
```

Or using [Array#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-each):

```
n.each do |x| # same as array.each.each
  p x
  p n.next
end
```

Also in Ruby you reach end the iteration signal:

```
6.times do
  p n.next
end
# `next': iteration reached an end (StopIteration)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just trying to print each element of the Array?

```
[1,2,3,4,5].each {|n| puts n}
```

Comment: ...or puts `[1,2,3,4,5]`. I initially interpreted the question as you did, but I think the OP wants to know how to display two consecutive elements per "Iteration", when using an enumerator.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a direct equivalent of [Python's iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator), you should check out [`Enumerator#next`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) for a very similar API

```
arr = [1, 2, 3].to_enum
#<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>
arr.next
# 1

for x in arr do
    puts x
    puts arr.next
end

#1
#2
#2
#3
#3
#StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

Comment: This is basically the same code as OP already had. `[1,2,3].to_enum` and `[1,2,3].each` with no block are functionally equivalent.

Comment: The documentation says that calling next "returns the next object in the enumerator, and moves the internal position forward." The point is that in your and my  example calling next inside the for loop doesn't change the position. That's why you get 2 and 3 twice...

Comment: @marcus are you just looking for [Enum#peek](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek)?

Comment: `arr` is perhaps not the best name for an enumerator.

Answer (score 0):

`each_cons` is what you need. But this method has a downside that is the `current` will not print last element of the array. Please keep in mind this.

```rb
[1,2,3,4,5].each_cons(2) { |current,next_val| puts next_val }
```

Comment: `1` has gone astray.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, but I mentioned it :) It depends on the usage. If developer knows the language boundaries there would be no any anomaly.